# How to redirect a wrong url to error page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello guys i am building up a project in php and facing issues regarding the wrong url my actual url is like this `http://localhost/blog_dir/blog/top-of-the-world` so when i am hitting to this url i can see the actual page that i want to see but when i am typing a wrong url like `http://localhost/blog_dir/blog/top-of-the-w` it shows me error like the notices, warnings and all the common errors of php into that page which is quite obvious as it is not getting the proper url. So what do i want to do is that if any user types wrong url then they must get redirected to the error page that i have created which is `err.php`. One more thing i would like to add is that the problem arises i think is due to the codes that i have written in my `.htaccess`. So i am adding up my `.htacces` code here

```
RewriteEngine On 
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/blog_dir/err.php

#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/\.]+)?$ blog-de.php?post=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I hope you could help me out with my project....

Answer (score 0):

This one can resolve your issue :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 path_to_error_page
```

> NB: replace **path_to_error_page** with the path to the error page.

Comment: i have used the path

Comment: and, what's happened?

Comment: @Babai the path not the url, is on your filesystem, ex. `ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html`

Comment: @the_nuts i have also used the path but the same result

Comment: @Mohammed Yassine CHABLI the way you have showed to me

Comment: i have used like this `ErrorDocument 404 /err.php` but the same result its showing those notices and all

Comment: you should handle that in your php application, not in the .htaccess configuration, because you pass everything inside blog to the PHP file, so apache doesn't know if the URL exists of not

Comment: @the_nuts yes you are absolutely right but how can i do that

Comment: @the_nuts also if i am changing any codes to my .htaccess then it is affecting my site but i dont know how to do that in php file can you suggest me any idea?????

Comment: Thanks guys for contacting  Mohammed Yassine CHABLI and the_nuts i have solved the issue...And you were right it was to be done in the php file!!! Coding rocks!!!!!!

Comment: how to do that? after you search in the db and you find that the post doesn't exist, show a "not found" message/page